# How to filter out data with conditional statement for series of numbers in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, missing-data, data-wrangling

#### Data

Here is the data for my example:

```
#### Create Data ####
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(NA,1,1,1,0), 
                 X2 = c(1,1,1,0,0),
                 X3 = c(1,1,NA,0,0),
                 X4 = c(1,1,1,1,NA),
                 X5 = c(1,1,1,0,NA),
                 X6 = c(1,NA,1,1,NA)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

#### Problem

When you print the data, it looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     1     1    NA
3     1     1    NA     1     1     1
4     1     0     0     1     0     1
5     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA
```

Basically there are cases where there is sporadic and random missingness in this data (rows 1-4). However, those with three zeroes in a row are those that have been converted to NA values after a stopping rule for multiple "wrong" answers (row 5). Theoretically I could just blindly remove these with the following code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ replace(.,
                          is.na(.),
                          0)))
```

And the NA's would be removed:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     1     1     0
3     1     1     0     1     1     1
4     1     0     0     1     0     1
5     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

However, it appears that this does not faithfully attack the problem. The NAs that are random are *actually* missing whereas the values that have been made NA are not. So I need a way to conditionally filter these values out for all cases where three 0s are recorded in a row, however I'm struggling with figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `is.na` we could `paste0` the rows to strings and check if number of matches with `111` are greater than zero using `stringi::stri_count` to create a flag. After that, `replace` `NA`s with zeros if a flag is present.

```
num_NA <- 3
flag <- apply(+(is.na(df)), 1, paste0, collapse='') |>
  stringi::stri_count(regex=paste(rep(1, num_NA), collapse='')) |> base::`>`(0)

df[flag, ] <- lapply(df[flag, ], \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))
df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
# 1 NA  1  1  1  1  1
# 2  1  1  1  1  1 NA
# 3  1  1 NA  1  1  1
# 4  1  0  0  1  0  1
# 5  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 0), X2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
    X3 = c(1, 1, NA, 0, 0), X4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA), X5 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, NA), X6 = c(1, NA, 1, 1, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Sorry, I think what you did is backwards from what I meant (I may have asked in an unclear way). The sequences of 3 or more NAs need to be replaced with 0 values, the other random NAs without patterns will remain NA.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Try to understand code that is provided to you. Removing the negation gives what you want. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Jay! That was what I needed. I had difficulty sifting through your answer since some of these commands are a bit unfamiliar to me. Appreciated either way.

Answer (score 0):

using `base`, and complicating things a little...

```
df2 <- rbind(df, df)
> df2
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  NA  1  1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  1  1 NA
3   1  1 NA  1  1  1
4   1  0  0  1  0  1
5   0  0  0 NA NA NA
6  NA  1  1  1  1  1
7   1  1  1  1  1 NA
8   1  1 NA  1  1  1
9   1  0  0  1  0  1
10  0  0  0 NA NA NA

# fiddle with it
df2[3,] <- c(0,NA,0,NA,0,NA)
df2[6,] <- c(NA,0,0,0,NA,NA)
```

You're at you earliest stage, data-wrangling.

```
df2
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  NA  1  1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  1  1 NA
3   0 NA  0 NA  0 NA
4   1  0  0  1  0  1
5   0  0  0 NA NA NA
6  NA  0  0  0 NA NA
7   1  1  1  1  1 NA
8   1  1 NA  1  1  1
9   1  0  0  1  0  1
10  0  0  0 NA NA NA
```

After applying @jay52 solution, above (entirely correct given the data offered), what should be said to test takers row 5 and 10, about the good fortune of test taker row 6?:

```
 df3
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  NA  1  1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  1  1 NA
3   0 NA  0 NA  0 NA
4   1  0  0  1  0  1
5   0  0  0  0  0  0
6  NA  0  0  0 NA NA
7   1  1  1  1  1 NA
8   1  1 NA  1  1  1
9   1  0  0  1  0  1
10  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

given that a series of 3 zeros in a row is intended per scoring protocol meant to have consequences (three in a row, it appears, and you're out). I would say that a resort to a `rle` style test is necessary to capture this circumstance, as unweildy as 'rle' seems to be continuing with `base`:

```
rle_lst_unc <- lapply(apply(df2, 1, rle), unclass)
for (k in 1:length(rle_lst_unc)) {
  idx_3_0[[k]] <- unname(rle_lst_unc[[k]]$values[rle_lst_unc[[k]]$lengths == 3] == 0)
}
true_3_0 <- which(lengths(idx_3_0) == 1)[which(unlist(idx_3_0) == TRUE)]
 df2[true_3_0, ] <- 0
df2
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  NA  1  1  1  1  1
2   1  1  1  1  1 NA
3   0 NA  0 NA  0 NA
4   1  0  0  1  0  1
5   0  0  0  0  0  0
6   0  0  0  0  0  0
7   1  1  1  1  1 NA
8   1  1 NA  1  1  1
9   1  0  0  1  0  1
10  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

And due to `rle`, `6` is treated the same as `5 & 10`.