# Calculate the length of an interval if data are equal to zero

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, intervals

I have a dataframe with time points and the corresponding measure of the activity in different subjects. Each time point it's a 5 minutes interval.

```
time        Subject1    Subject2
06:03:00    6,682129    8,127075
06:08:00    3,612061    20,58838
06:13:00    0           0
06:18:00    0,9030762   0
06:23:00    0           0
06:28:00    0           0
06:33:00    0           0
06:38:00    0           7,404663
06:43:00    0           11,55835
...
```

I would like to calculate the length of each interval that contains zero activity, as the example below:

```
             Subject 1    Subject 2
Interval_1   1            5
Interval_2   5
```

I have the impression that I should solve this using loops and conditions, but as I am not so experienced with loops I do not know where to start. Do you have any idea to solve this? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for making your first question clear and nicely illustrated with a small example! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle()` to find runs of consecutive values and the length of the runs. We need to filter the results to only runs where the value is 0:

```
result = lapply(df[-1], \(x) with(rle(x), lengths[values == 0]))
result
# $Subject1
# [1] 1 5
# 
# $Subject2
# [1] 5
```

As different subjects can have different numbers of 0-runs, the results make more sense in a `list` than a rectangular data frame.

Comment: Dear Gregor, thank you so much! I didn't know rle() function, it works perfectly!

Comment: An additional question Gregor: if I understand well, the condition "values ==0" will get the results for only runs with the value of zero. If now I want to do the same exercise but for the length of each interval where there is activity, is it enough to just change "values > 0"?

Comment: Assuming all your activities are positive values, then yes. Otherwise use `values != 0` if activities can have negative or positive values.

Comment: And can both `lengths` and `values` be specified, or would that necessarily be 2 lapply(s) [case of for loop on rle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915987/how-to-filter-out-data-with-conditional-statement-for-series-of-numbers-in-r/73916481#73916481), where I definitely struggled to adjust to lapply.

Comment: You could do `lapply(df[-1], \(x) rle(x > 0))`  to get all the RLE ouptut. Or maybe something like `lapply(df[-1], \(x) with(rle(x > 0), data.frame(duration = lengths, active = values)))` looks pretty nice